# AWS Lambda - failes when I try to calculate the diff between two binary files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to create a Lambda function to calculate the diff between two binary files, each 5MB.

I created the function in "default bootstrap" in custom runtime.

When I run the command inside the Lambda function:

`diff -a file_1 file_2 > diff_file`

The function fails, and prints:

`REPORT RequestId: ......   Duration: 304.51 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 73 MB  Init Duration: 46.35 ms`

Without explaining why it fails.

This is the full function:

```
#!/bin/bash

function handler () {
    cd /mnt/myefs/test/
    diff -a xaa xab > diff.file
}
```

I have the files `xaa` and `xab` in efs connected to the Lambda function.

- When I download the files to `/tmp/` and do the `diff -a`, I get the same error.
- I use `diff -a` to get the diff in text format.

How can I run diff command inside a Lambda function?

P.s. when I run `diff --help` I see the usage of the command, so the function has this command, but I'm not able to use it.

---

UPDATE:

- I did timeout of 15 mins, and it fails much sooner.
- When I run `echo` before and after the `diff`, I don't see any output, and I see the function fails. But when I comment out the `diff`, and only run `echo`, I see the echos.
- **IMPORTANT** - Something I noticed now, is that the function creates the diff file, but fails after it created it (I can see the diff file inside the EFS).

Comment: I have never seen an AWS Lambda function run bash code. Can you point us to how this custom runtime was written? Have you ever had the custom runtime working (eg sending an `echo` command that appears in CloudWatch Logs)? Also, what are you actually trying to accomplish from this code -- that is, what will you be doing with the results of the `diff` command and _why_ are you writing this code? The more information you provide, the easier it will be for us to offer appropriate suggestions (eg doing a diff in Python instead of shell).

Comment: Yes, simple Linux commands are working (i ran `ls` and `echo` etc). I chose the `default bootstrap` runtime for the function.

Comment: Your output is not displaying an error message. It is possible that your AWS Lambda function is configured to timeout after 3 seconds, but the `diff` is taking longer. Try increasing the timeout. Also, try putting an `echo` before and after the diff, to help with debugging and see where the script got to before it failed or timed-out.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I added update in the question. Thanks (:

Comment: I wonder if the exit return codes for `diff` are causing the failure? When a difference is found between files, it returns `1`, which might be interpreted as an error. Again, I'll mention that it would be worthwhile explaining _why_ you are doing this in a shell and what you are wanting to accomplish, because it might be better done through a Python script rather than calling shell in this manner.